# Generic Binary Search Tree class written in C#

Tags: c#, tree, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinarySearchTree<int> bst = new BinarySearchTree<int>();
            bst.Insert(1);
            bst.Insert(3);
            bst.Insert(5);
            bst.Insert(2); 
            bst.Insert(21);
            bst.Insert(4, bst.root); 
            System.Console.WriteLine(bst.FindByValue(4,bst.root).data);
        }
    }

    public class BinNode<T> where T:IComparable
    {
        //constructors
        public BinNode(T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public BinNode() { }
        //properties 
        public BinNode<T> right {get; set;} = null;
        public BinNode<T> left {get; set;} = null;
        public T data {get;set;}
    }


    public class BinarySearchTree<T> where T:IComparable
    {
        public BinNode<T> root {get; set;} = null; 

        //recursively insert new node into the bst instance with T data 
        public void Insert(T data, BinNode<T> node)
        { 

            if (data.CompareTo(node.data) > 0)
            {
                if (node.right == null)
                {
                    node.right = new BinNode<T>(data); 
                    return;
                }
                Insert(data, node.right);
                System.Console.WriteLine("right");
            }

            else if (data.CompareTo(node.data) < 0)
            {
                if (node.left == null)
                {
                    node.left = new BinNode<T>(data);
                    return;
                }
                Insert(data, node.left);
                System.Console.WriteLine("left");
            }
        }

        //normal insertion method (inserts T data into a bst instance)
        public void Insert(T data)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                root = new BinNode<T>(data);
            }

            BinNode<T> current = root; 

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (data.CompareTo(current.data) > 0)
                {
                    if (current.right != null)
                    {
                        current = current.right; 
                        continue;
                    }
                    current.right = new BinNode<T>(data); 
                } 

                else if (data.CompareTo(current.data) < 0)
                {
                    if (current.left != null)
                    {
                        current = current.left;
                        continue;
                    }
                    current.left = new BinNode<T>(data); 
                }

                else
                {
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        //insert all elements from an array
        public void InsertFromArray(T[] array)
        {
            foreach(T t in array)
            {
                this.Insert(t); 
            }
        }
        //get the last level in the bst instance
        public int GetLevel(BinNode<T> node, int current=1)
        {
            int right = 0 ;
            int left = 0 ;            

            if (node.right != null)
            {
                right =  GetLevel(node.right, current+1);
            }

            if (node.left != null)
            {
                left = GetLevel(node.right, current+1); 
            }

            if (right == 0 && left == 0) return current; //this is readable in my opinion but according to best practices (microsoft), only one operation per line is good, so should this be changed or is it okay

            else 
            { 
                return right > left ? right : left; //is this acceptable?
            }

        }
        //get a queue of all the values in a given level
        public void GetOnLevel(BinNode<T> node, int curLevel, int trgLevel, Queue<T> result)            
        {
            if (curLevel == trgLevel)
            {
                result.Enqueue(node.data);
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.left != null)
                {
                    GetOnLevel(node.left, curLevel+1, trgLevel, result);
                }

                if(node.right != null)
                {
                     GetOnLevel(node.right, curLevel+1, trgLevel, result); 
                }
            } 
        }

        //returns the node that holds data equivalent to T data
        public BinNode<T> FindByValue(T data, BinNode<T> node)
        {
            if (node == null) return null; 

            if (data.Equals(node.data))
            {
                return node;
            }

            if (data.CompareTo(node.data) > 0)
            {
                return FindByValue(data, node.right);
            }
            else if (data.CompareTo(node.data) < 0)
            {
                return FindByValue(data, node.left); 
            }

            else return null; 
        }

    }
}
```

I'm wondering whether the lines

> ```
> if (right == 0 && left == 0) return current;
> ```

… and

> ```
> return right > left ? right : left;
> ```

are acceptable for readability and maintainability.
As well as any other improvements I can make to my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether the lines
>
> ```
> if (right == 0 && left == 0) return current;
> ```
>
> … and
>
> ```
> return right > left ? right : left;
> ```
>
> are acceptable for readability and maintainability.

In my option they aren't but not because of the conditions but because of the suboptimal naming of the variables. I had to look twice at your code to understand what you are doing here as you usually use `left` and `right` to adress the nodes. Here however you are talking *levels*:

> ```
> int right = 0 ;
> int left = 0 ;            
>
> if (node.right != null)
> {
>     right =  GetLevel(node.right, current+1);
> }
>
> if (node.left != null)
> {
>     left = GetLevel(node.right, current+1); 
> }
> ```

Name them `rightLevel` and `leftLevel` and I think it should be clear what their purpose is.

---

Some more observations about the rest of the code:

Be consistent, if you call the main class `BinarySearchTree` then don't name the other one just `BinNode` but `BinaryTreeNode`

---

> ```
> public BinNode<T> right { get; set; } = null;
> public BinNode<T> left { get; set; } = null;
> ```

It's not necessary to set anything to `null`, it's `null` by default.

---

> ```
> public BinNode(T data)
> {
>     this.data = data;
> }
>
> public T data { get; set; }
> ```

It's pointless to have both the constructor and a get/set property. Make the property either readonly and required via constructor or leave it optional and get rid of the construtor.

---

All public members should be named with *PascalCase* unlike `left/right/data` where the convention is usually that `data` is to be called `Value`.

---

Don't put everything in a single class. Extract the `FindByValue` method into a new one that you could call `BinaryTreeSearch` and rename the old one to just `BinaryTree`.

---

You can make your life much easier if you override a few operators like `<`, `>`, `==` and `!=` so that you don't have to use `CompareTo` everywhere.

---

> ```
> node.left = new BinNode<T>(data);
> ```

Use helper variables so you don't have to repeat yourself so much.

---

In

> ```
> public void InsertFromArray(T[] array)
> ```

and then

> ```
> foreach (T t in array)
> ```

you shouldn't use abbreviations like `t` or general names like `array`. Call it `item` and `source`. In fact this could be even an `IEnumerable` and be an extension. A general convention is to call it `AddRange` or in this case `InsertRange`.

---

> ```
> public void GetOnLevel(BinaryTreeNode<T> node, int curLevel, int trgLevel, Queue<T> result)
> ```

More ugly abbreviations.

---

### Example

So, this is how it could look when optimized a little bit. I'm not saying it's pefect yet but I find it's already much better and easier to read then before.

This is the new `BinaryTreeNode` class that now implement all suggestions:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is BinaryTreeNode<T> other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(Value, other.Value)) return true;
            return Value.Equals(other.Value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode();

    public static bool operator ==(BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right) => ReferenceEquals(left, right) || (left?.Equals(right) ?? false);
    public static bool operator !=(BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right) => !(left == right);

    public static bool operator <(BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right) => left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value) < 0;
    public static bool operator >(BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right) => left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value) > 0;
}
```

This is the much easier to read `BinaryTree`

```
public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Root { get; set; }

    //recursively insert new node into the bst instance with T data 
    public void Insert(T value, BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
    {
        var nodeToInsert = new BinaryTreeNode<T> { Value = value };

        if (nodeToInsert > node)
        {
            if (node.Right == null)
            {
                node.Right = nodeToInsert;
            }
            else
            {
                Insert(value, node.Right);
                Console.WriteLine("right");
            }
        }

        if (nodeToInsert < node)
        {
            if (node.Left == null)
            {
                node.Left = nodeToInsert;
            }
            else
            {
                Insert(value, node.Left);
                Console.WriteLine("left");
            }
        }
    }

    //normal insertion method (inserts T data into a bst instance)
    public void Insert(T value)
    {
        var nodeToInsert = new BinaryTreeNode<T> { Value = value };

        if (Root == null)
        {
            Root = nodeToInsert;
        }

        var current = Root;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (nodeToInsert > current)
            {
                if (current.Right != null)
                {
                    current = current.Right;
                    continue;
                }
                current.Right = nodeToInsert;
                continue;
            }

            if (nodeToInsert < current)
            {
                if (current.Left != null)
                {
                    current = current.Left;
                    continue;
                }
                current.Left = nodeToInsert;
                continue;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    //insert all elements from an array
    public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            Insert(item);
        }
    }
    //get the last level in the bst instance
    public int GetLevel(BinaryTreeNode<T> node, int current = 1)
    {
        int right = 0;
        int left = 0;

        if (node.Right != null)
        {
            right = GetLevel(node.Right, current + 1);
        }

        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            left = GetLevel(node.Right, current + 1);
        }

        if (right == 0 && left == 0) return current; //this is readable in my opinion but according to best practices (microsoft), only one operation per line is good, so should this be changed or is it okay

        else
        {
            return right > left ? right : left; //is this acceptable?
        }

    }
    
    //get a queue of all the values in a given level
    public void GetOnLevel(BinaryTreeNode<T> node, int curLevel, int trgLevel, Queue<T> result)
    {
        if (curLevel == trgLevel)
        {
            result.Enqueue(node.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.Left != null)
            {
                GetOnLevel(node.Left, curLevel + 1, trgLevel, result);
            }

            if (node.Right != null)
            {
                GetOnLevel(node.Right, curLevel + 1, trgLevel, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the new `BinaryTreeSearch`

```
public class BinaryTreeSearch
{
    //returns the node that holds data equivalent to T data
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> FindNode<T>(T value, BinaryTreeNode<T> source) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (source == null) return null;
        
        var nodeToFind = new BinaryTreeNode<T> { Value = value };

        if (nodeToFind == source)
        {
            return source;
        }

        if (nodeToFind > source)
        {
            return FindNode<T>(value, source.Right);
        }
        
        if (nodeToFind < source)
        {
            return FindNode<T>(value, source.Left);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope I didn't broke anything but it should be more of an example rather then fully tested code.

Comment: Thanks, anything else I could improve?

Comment: @ItayElgard I forgot about your question, sorry ;-) I've added a  few more points to the review.